# Clarification of Machine Learning Terminology

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, terminology

Terms like Machine Learning, Statistical Learning, Statistical Machine Learning and Deep Learning are often used interchangeably.

Is following structure true/accurate as far as someone could classify it?

- Machine Learning is the main topic and one branch of the whole AI field.

  - Statistical Learning and Statistical Machine Learning are the same. It's a subbranch of Machine Learning, a tool  which uses statistical approaches to extract information from data.
  - Deep Learning is another tool of machine learning. It's Not clearly separated from Statistical Machine Learning. Some people call it deep learning, when it has more than two hidden layers, since statistical machine learning also uses neural networks sometimes.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you! Well this answer fits somehow. Of course such questions are always a bit meta, but this one can actually be answered quite clearly in my opinion. I‘ll might answer the questions with my latest findings by my self.